# Wrong icon size in Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, image, resolution, galaxy, dpi

i have to do an update release in my app,
i've changed a control in an internal activity.

Now during the testing, i 'have noted that the app has a problem showing icons on main page, but only in a Samsung Galaxy Nexus device.

I have checked all the code, i've made test with other device with same resolution (xhdpi) and in all other devices work fine, only in the Galaxy Nexus show the icon (not all, 8 on 9) too large.

here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Any suggestion to understand this problem and solve it?

many thanks

Comment: to mean it seams like you scaled the other pics but not the one with the letter

Answer (score 0):

I've Found the problem!

I'ts a bug of android, i've set the targetSdkVersion to 19, like the suggestion of eclipse, and i was them that give the error.

Now i set the targetSdkVersion to 17 and all work fine!

Comment: You should always target the latest SDK version, no matter what. Try to find a work-around that doesn't involve lowering the target SDK.

Comment: Why?
there can be a problen if don't set the last SDK version in the target?

Comment: if you don't target the latest SDK, it will basically run your app in a "compatibility mode" and some things may not work correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! :)

Now i try to make it work with the last target of sdk!